# WordPress > bbPress > Search > PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php, wordpress

**CentOS** Linux 7.9.2009 (Core)
**Plesk** Obsidian 18.0.51
**PHP** 8.1.17 (up-to-date)
**WordPress** 6.2 (up-to-date)
**X Theme** 10.1.10 (up-to-date)

**php.ini**
`memory_limit 512M`
(confirmed by checking the phpinfo() page)

**wp-config.php**
`define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );`
`define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT' , '512M' );`
`@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '512M' );`

Every time I run a search of my website using bbPress' built-in search function I receive this error:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/redacted.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/cache.php on line 154PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0', referer: https://redacted.com/forums/search/
```

I have disabled every plugin except bbPress and WooCommerce (for some reason disabling WooCommerce breaks my site).

I tried switching to a vanilla WordPress theme, but for some reason doing so breaks bbPress.

Answer (score 0):

This [seems to be an issue](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/critical-error-after-6-2-upgrade/) with WordPress 6.2.

I guess I'll have to wait for a fix.